# How to select multiple value in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation

I cant select multiple items from SharePoint list when we have large data in list. When we have large data, it shows items without check box like this
[image]

plz help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have same issue...Please someone help me....

Comment: Are your columns indexed?